# Groovy remove from map

Tags: java, groovy

The list below contains a collection of `id`'s

```
List id_wanted = ['3894586', '2786438236', '895673985']
```

Given the list above, How do I remove elements from the JSON below that match with the id above List?

JSON:

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "name": "lion",
            "countries": [
                {
                    "name": "kenya",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "young male"
                            ],
                            "age": "2y",
                            "id": "2837492"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "tanzania",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "cub"
                            ],
                            "age": "0y",
                            "id": "3894586"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "south africa",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "adult lioness"
                            ],
                            "age": "10y",
                            "id": "495684576"
                        },
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "young female"
                            ],
                            "age": "4y",
                            "id": "2786438236"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "giraffe",
            "countries": [
                {
                    "name": "zambia",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "ex captivity"
                            ],
                            "age": "20y",
                            "id": "343453509"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "kenya",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "male"
                            ],
                            "age": "17y",
                            "id": "85604586"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "uganda",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "young female"
                            ],
                            "age": "4y",
                            "id": "895673985"
                        },
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "none"
                            ],
                            "age": "11y",
                            "id": "39860394758936764"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For example, the following block would be removed from the JSON above because `id` matches with the List `id_wanted`

```
                    {
                        "features": [
                            "young female"
                        ],
                        "age": "4y",
                        "id": "2786438236"
                    }
```

Comment: So you are always wanting to remove facts?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Yes @Paul King, I will always want to remove facts

Comment: @daggett — How do I update my JSON map, so that I remove elements under “facts” if “facts” contain a value for “id” that corresponds/matches to a value in the List “id_wanted” ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json is a String in a variable `inputJson`, it's probably easier to build a new Json document from the original with those values filtered out:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputJson)

List id_wanted = ['3894586', '2786438236', '895673985']

def result = new JsonBuilder([
    animals: json.animals.collect {[
        name: "$it.name",
        countries: it.countries.collect { [
            name: "$it.name",
            facts: it.facts.findAll { !(it.id in id_wanted) }
        ]}
    ]}
]).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your `original` json and modify the resulted data structure in-place using handy `*.` spread operator:

```
def json = slurper.parseText(original)
json.animals*.countries*.facts*.each { facts ->
    facts.removeAll { fact -> fact.id in id_wanted }
}
def filtered = new JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString()
println(filtered)
```

Output (with facts from `id_wanted` removed):

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "name": "lion",
            "countries": [
                {
                    "name": "kenya",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "young male"
                            ],
                            "age": "2y",
                            "id": "2837492"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "tanzania",
                    "facts": [

                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "south africa",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "adult lioness"
                            ],
                            "age": "10y",
                            "id": "495684576"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "giraffe",
            "countries": [
                {
                    "name": "zambia",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "ex captivity"
                            ],
                            "age": "20y",
                            "id": "343453509"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "kenya",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "male"
                            ],
                            "age": "17y",
                            "id": "85604586"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "uganda",
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "features": [
                                "none"
                            ],
                            "age": "11y",
                            "id": "39860394758936764"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```